# Postgres / SQL count across multiple tables based on multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables, and the goal is a simple true/false (or count if it's easier) for whether there exists either an `AccountLink` or a `ResourceLink` based on given `User.uuid` and `Resource.uuid`.

#### Minimal working example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09144/1

#### Goal

True/false response based on `User.uuid` and `Resource.uuid`, which are unrelated.

#### Schema

```
User
- id
- uuid

Resource
- id
- account_id
- uuid

AccountLink
- id
- account_id
- user_id

ResourceLink
- id
- resource_id
- user_id
```

#### Currently working

Gives `id` list instead of true/false, which can be handled in application code, but the query itself is also inefficient:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM "AccountLinks"
WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM "Users" WHERE uuid = ?) 
  AND account_id = (SELECT account_id FROM "Resources" WHERE uuid = ?)
UNION
SELECT id
FROM "ResourceLinks"
WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM "Users" WHERE uuid = ?)
  AND resource_id = (SELECT id FROM "Resources" WHERE uuid = ?)
```

Is there a way to find the correct `user` and `resource` once based on their `uuid`, and then use those `id` properties to count across multiple tables?

Comment: You mention count and true/false, but your query return a list of id. so not sure what result you want

Comment: Is `user.uuid` related to `resource.uuid`? or are two separated inputs?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza updated my question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want a `cross join` with additional information brought in:

```sql
select 
  (exists (select 1
     from "AccountLinks" al
     where al.user_id = u.id and al.account_id = r.account_id
  )) as has_accountlink,
  (exists (select 1
     from "ResourceLinks" rl
     where rl.user_id = u.id and rl.resource_id = r.id
  )) as has_resourcelink
from "Users" u cross join
     "Resources" r 
where u.uuid = ? and r.uuid = ?
```

Comment: You miss the `LEFT JOIN ON` condition. Also `resource.uuid` seem to have an input variable too.

Comment: I'll look into `cross join`.  Meanwhile `uuid` is different for `User` and for `Resource`.  I have updated my question to reflect this more clearly.